# Use of Stone-Weierstrass Theorem for $1/z$ on complex circle

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula, weierstrass-approximation

Let $C:=\{x\in\mathbb{C}:|x|=1\}$ be the complex circle and $f:C\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ the mapping $x\mapsto 1/x$.
From the Stone-Weierstrass theorem I get $\oint fdx =0$, but by Cauchy's theorem $\oint fdx =2\pi i$.
It must be that I'm using the Stone-Weierstrass wrongly, but I don't see where.
Can you help me?

The complex Stone-Weierstrass theorem says:

> If $X$ is a compact Hausdorff space and $A$ is a closed subalgebra of  $\mathcal{C}(X,\mathbb{C})$, which separates points, contains a non-zero constant function, and contains the conjugate of each of its functions, then $A$ equals $\mathcal{C}(X,\mathbb{C})$.

Here, $\mathcal{C}(X,\mathbb{C})$ is the linear space of continuous functions $X\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$, equipped with the supremum-norm.
$C$ is compact and Hausdorff.
The set of polynomials forms a closed subalgebra of $\mathcal{C}(C,\mathbb{C})$, which separates points, contains a non-zero constant function, and contains the conjugate of each of its functions.
So, for all $\epsilon>0$, there exists a polynomial $p_\epsilon$, such that $|p(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$ for all $x\in C$.
Next, using the triangular inequality:
$$
\left|\oint fdx\right|=\left|\oint f-p_\epsilon dx\right|+\left|\oint p_\epsilon dx\right|
$$
By Cauchy's integral formula, $\oint p_\epsilon dx=0$. So, choosing $\gamma:[0,1]\rightarrow C$, with $t\mapsto e^{2\pi i t}$,
$$
=\left|\oint f-p_\epsilon dx\right|
=\left|\int_0^1 (f-p_\epsilon)\circ\gamma(t)\cdot\gamma'(t) dt\right|
\leq\int_0^1\left| (f-p_\epsilon)\circ\gamma(t)\right|\left|\gamma'(t)\right| dt
\leq \epsilon 2\pi
$$
Since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary, it follows that $\left|\oint fdx\right|=0$ and therefore $\oint fdx=0$.
But we know that $\oint fdx=2\pi i$. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: No, the class of polynomials is _not_ closed under complex conjugation! If $p(z)=z$ then $\overline{p(z)}=\overline z$, not a polynomial. (So in fact what you've shown here is that there is no sequence of polynomials that tends to $1/z$ uniformly on the circle $|z|=1$.)

Comment: Either that, or you talk of complex polynomials in $x,y$, which is closed under conjugation, but $\oint p(z)\;dz = 0$ may fail for such a polynomial.

Comment: Thanks David and GEdgar, this resolves my issue. David, if you write your comment as an answer I will accept it.